# how to reduce the performance issue of two hetrogeneous databases connected via database link

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have connected Oracle database with an Azure SQL Server database via a database link.
I am trying to fetch the data of Azure SQL Server database in Oracle and it is working fine.

But when I am joining one Oracle table and one Azure SQL Server table it is taking too much time to fetch the records.

For example:.
I have one table temp_one in Oracle database and one table temp_two in Azure SQL Server database having dblink like temp.sql.hl.com.
I joined them.

```sql
SELECT "EmpAddress",EMPLOYEE_ID
FROM temp_one a
INNER join temp_two@temp.sql.hk.com b
on a.EMPLOYEE_ID = b."EmpID";
```

Even this normal join is taking 8 seconds.

Note: I am trying to fetch the data in Oracle.

Please help me to resolve it.

Comment: Your query has no filtering predicate. It will read the entire table `temp_one`. That's bound to be slow.

Comment: With no predicates, you'd need to fetch the entire `temp_two` table locally to be able to do the join in Oracle (or push the entire `temp_one` to SQL Server and have it do the join there and return the results to Oracle but that's an unlikely plan).  Unless `temp_two` is small, that's unlikely to be fast.  You'd probably need to replicate the data locally if you want to improve the performance.

Comment: This question had essentially the same response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72412674/connect-to-sql-azure-tables-from-oracle-database-using-dev-link. Your best bet is to replicate the data to Oracle using materialized views and then do the joins locally. Without predicates in your query you'd be essentially doing that anyway.